# Need to update Tamil font in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I need to update one SQL in Oracle (Solaris OS ) which is having Tamil font. Please let me know which NLS_CHARACTER_SET  I need to set it for the session to update my query.

Comment: Hi, where is the SQL stored, in a procedure or trigger?
I'm affraid I don't understand your question, because if SQL is already in DB, it is correctly configured to store Tamil font values.
If you don't see it well in your SQLPLUS client maybe is your client who needs to update charset, or your OS.
In that case, change NLS_CHARACTER_SET will not work.

Comment: Hi Biggum.. Thank you.... My SQL is a single update quey which is having Tamil font. This is the first update we are trying in Tamil font  I could see it in client OS but couldn't not see it in Database.. The reason is my DB doesn't allow the Tamil font hence  I am going to change my DB Charset.  As you said, NLS_CHAR_SET  change will not workout here.